# Google Foobar challenge: Rabbit Test Subjects

Tags: python, programming-challenge

> The diabolical Professor Boolean has captured you and a group of your
>   hapless rabbit kin as test subjects for his terrible experiments!
>   You're not sure what his real plans are, but currently it seems he's
>   trying to make everyone faster and smarter? He's exposing rabbit test
>   subjects to novel chemicals, genetic manipulations, and pathogens;
>   then measuring their completion time for various puzzles and
>   exercises. Then again, there's a rumor he's developing a kind of
>   zombie rabbit. You don't want to become a zombit!
>
> Unfortunately, due to insubordination, and laziness, Professor Boolean
>   just "eliminated" the lab assistant tracking all data from this
>   research. Now, he's forcing you to sort through the notes and find
>   something useful from the chaos. You have no choice but to abide by
>   your captors evil rules. For now.
>
> Of the subjects that have survived, each has a distinct file, with
>   anywhere from 1 to 100 measurements of completion time for the tests.
>   The measurements from the before and after cases are listed
>   separately, but the ordering has been mixed up. You have to figure out
>   the degree of improvement (0% to 99%, rounded to the nearest whole
>   number) based on the two lists of results.
>
> For example, if the first list of times is [22.2, 46, 100.8] and the
>   second list is [23, 11.1, 50.4] you would return 50, because the times
>   got 50% shorter: the 22.2 entry improved to 11.1, the 46 improved to
>   23, and the 100.8 improved to 50.4. Even though the data points are in
>   different order, each improves by the same amount.
>
> Write a function `answer(x, y)` which takes two lists of floating
>   point performance scores and returns the improvement percentage,
>   rounded to the nearest integer.
>
> Test cases:
>
> Inputs:
>
> ```
> (double list) y = [1.0]
> (double list) x = [1.0]
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> (int) 0
> ```
>
> Inputs:
>
> ```
> (double list) y = [2.2999999999999998, 15.0, 102.40000000000001, 3486.8000000000002]
> (double list) x = [23.0, 150.0, 1024.0, 34868.0]
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> (int) 90
> ```

The test cases are successful, but for some reason when I try to verify my answer, it says: There was a problem evaluating your code.

Is there a better way to solve this?

```
def answer(y,x):
    totalTime1 = 0
    totalTime2 = 0
    for time in x:
        totalTime1 += time
    for time in y:
        totalTime2 += time
    improvement = (1-(totalTime1 / totalTime2)) * 100
    return int(improvement)
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Does your code work as expected? While it does pass the test cases, you do say how the service rejects your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one thing, the assignment was to define a function `answer(x, y)`, not `answer(y, x)`.  You could also put the built-in function `sum()` to use.  I believe the key point is *rounded to the nearest whole number*.  `int()` always goes down.  That is `4.9` results in `4`, but rounding would result in `5`.  You can use the built-in function `round()`.  In Python3 it returns an integer, but in Python2 it returns a float.  To take care of both cases, convert the rounded version to an int:

```
def answer(x, y):
    return int(round((1-(sum(y)/sum(x))) * 100))
```

Comment: The assignment was answer(x,y) but in their solution.py file, the header was answer(y,x), and thanks totally forgot that it was round not truncate.